# configure rclone drive from shell script

Tags: shell, rclone

I want to use a shell script to configure rclone to use a OneDrive. The only user interaction I want is for authentication. Currently, I am using the command line :

```
$ rclone config create MyOneDrive onedrive --onedrive-drive-type business
```

But, when I want to list the drive content, I got the error :

```
$ rclone ls MyOneDrive:
2020/02/24 22:28:21 Failed to create file system for "MyOneDrive:": unable to get drive_id and drive_type - if you are upgrading from older versions of rclone, please run `rclone config` and re-configure this backend
```

Effectively, when I hit `rclone config` and edit the remote, the `drive_id` is found and saved in the config. My problem is that I do not want to use the second `rclone config` step. Why the `drive_id` is not found when running the first command ? Thanks

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you figured out the solution yet?

Comment: Nop, for onedrive, you can use https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive.